# MVC Routing issue 404 received

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am trying to call an action method through ajax but am getting a 404. To illustrate, the following is my ajax:

```
  $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Product/LandingPage",
            data: {trackingCode: trackingCode, productId: productId},
            success: function (data) {
                alert("I worked!");
            }
        });
```

From alerting out the paramters I can see both trackingCode and productId are being successfully set so that's not the issue. I thought, to test this, I should be able to direclty call the URL like so:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/Product/LandingPage?trackingCode=fgdfg&productId=213456
```

However, when I try that I get a 404 error, so maybe the routing isn't working. I've added the following route:

```
            routes.MapRoute(
           "Product_LandingPage",
           "Product/LandingPage",
           new { controller = "Product", action = "LandingPage" }, new {  trackingCode = UrlParameter.Optional ,productId = @"\d+" });
```

But I still get a 404. This is my Product controller method:

```
 [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get | HttpVerbs.Head)]
    public ActionResult LandingPage(string trackingCode, int productId)
    {
        //Some magic in here
    }
```

I've a feeling I'm missing something obvious here. Any ideas as to why I'm getting a 404?

Note this could be some other code causing an issue, I just want to sanity check what I'm doing to rule out a stupid mistake on my part.

Comment: ***Default*** route is enough for that URL. Could you remove `Product_LandingPage` route and try again?

Comment: Indeed that's exactly what I thought, but I got a 404 before adding the route and I get it again if I remove the route. It could be something else in the controller declaration causing this, but I want to rule out my code being the issue.

Comment: Can you give examples of URLs that are working, either pages or api calls or both?

Comment: To that specific URL - nothing works when using AJAX, I just continually get a 404. Other controllers called in a similar manner work without issue.

Comment: Let forget about Ajax. Since it is ***Get*** method, you can test it in browser. Could you add the following default route ***only*** nothing else, and try again `routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new {controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional}`

Comment: Done...and it works. So presumably it's a conflicting route? But why / how would that cause a 404?

Comment: You could try Phil Haacks route debugger, see blog post: **http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx/**, NuGet package: **https://www.nuget.org/packages/routedebugger/**

Comment: Excellent idea, never used it before but just tried it and found the conflict with another route! Was driving me mad thinking I had some dodgy code in place but I didn't. Thanks for all help.

Answer (score 0):

Using Phil Haacks route debugger I found the issue, it was caused by another route, higher up the chain of route command. Restructuring has sorted this out. Thanks for all help.